# Markdown note taking with Dropbox sync

Tags: sync, notes, dropbox

How do I do all of the following with my Android phone?

- Read [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)-formatted notes stored in my Dropbox folder
- Show it as HTML in Android
- Optional editing from the phone

FWIW, the [iPhone already has an app](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/10/18/note-and-share-for-ios-markdown-dropbox-evernote-and-more/) that does this.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts.  Please see [this question about app recommendations](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/366/how-do-you-decide-whether-a-question-asks-for-shopping-recommendation) and its accepted answer, and modify your question accordingly to meet the guidelines in our [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: @Matthew - Thanks. Which guideline in the FAQ is not met by the question in its current form?

Comment: @sridhar_ratnakumar Here's another discussion of shopping recommendations that you might find helpful: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/164/shopping-recommendations Both discussions ought to help you understand the difference between a problem solving question and a request for shopping advice.

Comment: Rephrased the question to meet the guideline.

Comment: You can see the answer here https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208186/131553

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as both Epistle and its successor Draft are both no longer maintained and can no longer sync with Dropbox, this app [simply called "Notes" seems be the closest alternative to them.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.jacobras.notes)

Comment: I upvoted but essentially, the app does not support Markdown!